# Open a query and its visualization in Neo4J from browser

Tags: neo4j

I have a host running neo4j engine, say: neo4jhost:7474

I would like certain users to be able see query results in a browser, from a pre-generated link. Thus, user could explore the graph interactively, without messing with the query syntax.

For example: let the query be

```
(n)-[r]->(m) where n.id=123 return n,r,m
```

I need a URL link that produces the above mentioned query, but displays the result in a browser, in neo4j graph visualization format.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [Neo4j Browser](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser) does not have this feature.

However, you can use a graph visualization library to embed the graph visualization into your web application. Some examples of JavaScript graph visualization libraries:

- [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)
- [VivaGraphJS](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS)
- [Sigma](http://sigmajs.org/)
- [KeyLines](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/)
- [Alchemy.js](http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/)

Alternatively, since Neo4j Browser is an Open-source tool you can checkout the project and modify it to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, Neo4j browser does not have this functionality. However, you can have a look at the [popoto.js](http://www.popotojs.com/). It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but it has dynamic natural language query tracker and Cypher Query generation functionalities.
I suggest to inspect and do some re-engineering on the functions to figure out more details. Maybe it gives new ideas as well.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it was possible to open a browser passing a query as URL parameter, in an earlier version (2016). But I am not able to replicate that.